# PostgreSQL constraints - ON DELETE CASCADE not being restored

Tags: postgresql, cascade, database-backups

I have run into problems when restoring a PostgreSQL database schema in another server. More precisely, some of the tables don't seem to have the same foreign key constraints associated with them that they used to in the original database. For example, the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause seems to have completely evaporated from all of the constraint definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because the dumping procedure didn't backup the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clauses in your table definitions.

Firstly you should delete the foreign key constraints on your tables and then go on to altering them:

Something like the following:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY *your_table* DROP CONSTRAINT your_constraint;
```

After that, recreate the constraints with something like:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY your_table ADD CONSTRAINT your_constraint (...ON DELETE CASCADE, etc..);
```

Comment: Thanks,that was the problem,all the constraints where restored except on delete cascades.